# Freeze after "VM Swap Subsystem is ON"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

My Macbook pro 15" (early 2012) froze and I had to force restart it. But it freezes in startup too.

I noticed that it stops after "VM Swap Subsystem is ON" line in verbose mode.

Is there any solutions for this? 
How can I recover my OS X?

I didn't install or modified anything in the last few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to say what was the issue.

Logic board was dead and needed to be replaced. (hopefully I had 10 days of warranty left hehe)